# Next.js how to work with sheduled functions?

Tags: next.js

I want to create a scheduled function which will reset a prize on my website every night. In the function I need to call my database with some sensible data. Im wondering where is the perfect place to write the function and make it work? I just noticed that `_app.js` would probably make it? It seems like this page provides client and serverside so I can write a scheduled function calling my prize reset function giving sensible data to do that and Im fine? If I `console.log` this im getting the variable on serverside only. So everything looks good to me. Does someone have experience on this and can confirm this and/or show a better solution?

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

console.log('_app.js:' + process.env.JWT_SECRET)

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: are you using a custom server for deployment?

Comment: no, i dont use any custom server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a **cron** job, but you can't do it with Next.js API functions if you are not using a custom server.

Next.js API functions are **serverless** which means that there is no running server and functions are triggered as needed. To trigger the functions at a specific time, you would need to hit your API point from an *external* source.

For example, using github actions, you could hit your API endpoint, every 15 minutes. Make sure you have **authorization** check on your endpoint, and pass that authorization via *headers*.

```yaml
name: 15-minute-cron
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/15 * * * *'
jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Call our API route
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://yoursite.com/api/cron' \
          --header 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.API_SECRET_KEY }}'
```

More information in the [Vercel Docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/solutions/cron-jobs)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! So using a package like this doesnt work? https://github.com/kibertoad/toad-scheduler or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: It won't work. Because you need something that runs all the time 24/7 (like a regular server) and then you could a have a node.js application that uses that package, and it is able to trigger **cron** jobs at specified time or intervals.